# Аннотация типов TypeVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Почему нет разницы между `TypeVar('T')` и `TypeVar('T', contravariant=True)` работает одинаково и проходит проверки от `mypy`

```
from typing import TypeVar, List
#T = TypeVar('T')  # Определение T как контравариантного
T = TypeVar('T', contravariant=True)

def process_data(data: List[T]) -> None:
    for item in data:
        print(item)

object_list: List[object] = [1, 'hello', {'key': 'value'}]

process_data(object_list)
```

P.S.
`TypeVar('T')` - Это означает, что можно использовать только изначально указанный тип. Таким образом, параметр инвариантного универсального типа не является ни ковариантным, ни контрвариантным.